# Why Netcoreapp3.1 not Compatible with net5.0 Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-5, netcoreapp3.1

As per my understanding, `net5.0` is compatible with both `netcoreapp` and older `.net` versions.

I am trying to create an Azure function that targets netcoreapp3.1 and use a library that was built targetting net5.0. However, I am getting the following error, which indicates there is incompatibility issues.

> Error NU1202  Package XXX is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1).
> Package XXX supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)

I have quoted the above from **VS 2019** but replaced package name with XXX for privacy. The two strings in bracket are verbatim and I am not clear why `net5.0` is being listed as `.NETCoreApp, Version 5.0`.

Could someone explain what is going on and if there is anything I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 3):

> As per my understanding, net5.0 is compatible with both netcoreapp and older .net versions.

Yes, but not the other way round. There are things in .NET 5.0 which *aren't* in .NET Core 3.1.

You can target a framework for an application and then use a library targeting an *earlier* framework, but not the other way round. So for example, it would be fine for your Azure function to target .NET 6.0 and use a library targeted at .NET 5.0.

Basically, to solve your problem you'll either need to use a different library (or an earlier version of the library which targeted .NET Core 3.1, or maybe .NET Standard) or update to a more recent runtime.

Comment: When you say "update to a more recent runtime", I should have my Azure Function use .NET 5.0?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz-MSFT: Well ideally .NET 6.0 instead, given that .NET 5.0 will be out of support from early May 2022.